# How to loop in a nested Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Considering we have an Association:

```
<|a -> tr, b -> <|c -> <|d -> 12, e -> del, f -> <|h -> true, i -> false|>|>|>|>
```

How can I iterate through it, and delete the `key->val` where `val === del` and update the values that are `true` or `false` to be `True` and `False`,so that having as a result:

```
  <|a -> tr, b -> <|c -> <|d -> 12, f -> <|h -> True, i -> False|>|>|>|>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `DeleteCases` and `ReplaceAll` to accomplish this for your particular example:

```
data =  <|a -> tr, b -> <|c -> <|d -> 12, e -> del, f -> <|h -> true, i -> false|>|>|>|>;
DeleteCases[
  ReplaceAll[data, {true -> True, false -> False}],
  del,
  Infinity]
```

> <|a -> tr, b -> <|c -> <|d -> 12, f -> <|h -> True, i -> False|>|>|>|>

The Infinity, the last argument of `DeleteCases`, specifies that the deletion should occur at every level (and not just on the outer association). When you use `DeleteCases` on an association, it matches on the values of the association, so simply matching on del is sufficient in this case.

Note that if you explicitly want to check for a value being the same (=== or SameQ) as del, then you would want to replace the argument `del` to `DeleteCases` above with something like `val_ /; val === del`.

Comment: And what if I would also like to check the Keys? e.g. if the key is e I don't want to do anything with that pair?

Comment: In that case, you'd probably want something like `Association@DeleteCases[Normal[a], (Except[e] -> del)]`; the Normal call just turns the association into a list of rules so you can match on the entire rule; the `(Except[e] -> del)` is just a pattern that matches anything but e as the lhs of the rule and del as the rhs.